# Sumar elemento de «array» multidimensional

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente `Array` multidimensional:

```
[
  [ 
    {
    "l_grupo": "F003"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "45", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "375.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "46", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "52.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "47", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "116.0000000"
    }
  ],

  [ 
    {
      "l_grupo": "B003"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "21", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "35.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "18", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "88.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "15", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "93.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "16", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "112.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "17", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "78.0000000"
    }
  ]
]
```

Y deseo obtener la suma del campo `s_tota` por cada grupo y agregarlo al índice `0` donde está el campo `l_grupo` y obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
[
  [ 
    {
      "l_grupo": "F003", "total": "543.00"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "45", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "375.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "46", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "52.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "47", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "116.0000000"
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      "l_grupo": "B003" , "total": "406"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "21", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "35.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "18", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "88.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "15", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "93.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "16", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "112.0000000"
    },
    {
      "d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "17", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "78.0000000"
    }
  ]
]
```

He tratado de muchas formas pero no he podido lograrlo.

Comment: no entiendo de dónde sale 543.00 en el primer grupo donde dice F003

Comment: tu array marca un error de sintaxis, ¿también es parte del problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero que nada debes de recorrer el array para procesar la suma y agregarle la propiedad total a cada elemento, quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
var array = [[ 
{
"l_grupo": "F003"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "45", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "375.0000000"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "46", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "52.0000000"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "47", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "116.0000000"
}
],
[ {
"l_grupo": "B003"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "21", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "35.0000000"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "18", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "88.0000000"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "15", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "93.0000000"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "16", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "112.0000000"
},
{
"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "17", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "78.0000000"
}
]];

//console.log(array);

var new_array = [];
for ( var element = 0; element < array.length; element++ ) {
  var acumulador = 0;
  for ( var element_suma = 1; element_suma < array[element].length; element_suma++ ) {
    acumulador += ( parseFloat(array[element][element_suma].s_tota) );
  }
  array[element][0]["total"] = acumulador;
  //new_array.push();
}

console.log(array);
```

Nos ayudamos en cada vuelta del primer `form` de un acumulador, para después, dentro y anidado del primer `for`, recorremos a partir de la posición número 1 (no de la cero porque aquí no hay nada qué sacar y porque no existe nunca forma de sumar un `s_tota`) a sumar cada propiedad que encuentre con `s_tota`. Al final, al mismo array, le agregamos la propiedad `total` como te expliqué desde el principio.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: excelente muchas gracias @fernando Torres

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    let data = [
        [{
                "l_grupo": "F003"
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "01",
                "n_seri": "F003",
                "n_comp": "45",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "375.0000000"
         
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "01",
                "n_seri": "F003",
                "n_comp": "46",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "52.0000000"
          
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "01",
                "n_seri": "F003",
                "n_comp": "47",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "116.0000000"
            
            }
        ],
        [{
                "l_grupo": "B003"
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "03",
                "n_seri": "B003",
                "n_comp": "21",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "35.0000000"
             
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "03",
                "n_seri": "B003",
                "n_comp": "18",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "88.0000000"
              
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "03",
                "n_seri": "B003",
                "n_comp": "15",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "93.0000000"
              
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "03",
                "n_seri": "B003",
                "n_comp": "16",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "112.0000000"
                
            },
            {
                "d_anul": "0",
                "c_comp": "03",
                "n_seri": "B003",
                "n_comp": "17",
                "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000",
                "k_mone": "0",
                "s_tipc": "1.0000000",
                "s_tota": "78.0000000"
               
            }
        ]
    ];

    // recorremos el objeto
    for(x in data){
        // creamos una varibale temporal llamada tmp
        let tmp=0;
        // recorremos los objetos
        for(y in data[x]){
            // validamos que exista el llave "s_tota"
            if(data[x][y]["s_tota"]){
                // convertimos a float y lo sumamos a la varible temporal
                tmp += parseFloat(data[x][y]["s_tota"]);
                // por si queremos conservar los decimales
                //tmp += parseFloat(data[x][y]["s_tota"]).toFixed(7);
            }
        }
        // agregamos a la posiscion 0 del objeto la llave "total" con el valor de la suma en tmp
        data[x][0]["total"]=tmp;
        console.log(`para el l_grupo ${data[x][0]["l_grupo"]} el total es: ${data[x][0]["total"]}`);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar foreach's serian mas utiles:

```js
        const x = [
          [ 
          {"l_grupo": "F003"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "45", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "375.0000000"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "46", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "52.0000000"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "01", "n_seri": "F003", "n_comp": "47", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "116.0000000"}
          ],
          [ 
          {"l_grupo": "B003"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "21", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "35.0000000"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "18", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "88.0000000"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "15", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "93.0000000"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "16", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "112.0000000"},
          {"d_anul": "0", "c_comp": "03", "n_seri": "B003", "n_comp": "17", "f_comp": "2018-08-04 00:00:00.000", "k_mone": "0", "s_tipc": "1.0000000", "s_tota": "78.0000000"}
          ]
        ];

        x.forEach(elem => {
          let num = 0;
          elem.forEach(element => {
            if(element.s_tota){
              num += parseFloat(element.s_tota);
            }
          });
          elem[0].total = num;
        });
        
        console.log(x);
```